# How to get popup alert for message received in ios

Tags: ios, iphone

I am learning IOS and could not find that in a messaging app how to get the alert (popup box on screen and **NOT** a banner on top) for a message received (like in whatsapp or a built in messaging app). 
Also, is it possible to get the alert if the app is open (like in whatsapp if we are using whatsapp then wee do not receive any pop up or banner for the message received).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to receive popups in opened app you should create custom view. Native alerts about push notifications shown only if app in background or suspended and it's appearance customised by device settings
For example, you could use this [library](https://github.com/jmascia/KLCPopup) for popup box notifications or [this](https://github.com/AlvaroFranco/AFDropdownNotification) for banner style